# Django Template not rendering correctly

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

`app.views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

        class RegisterView(View):
            def get(self,request):
                return render(request, 'register.html' , { 'title' : 'Register Page'} );
```

`register.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' }

{% block head}
    {{title}}

{% endblock}


{% block content} 

    Register Page

{% endblock }
```

`base.html`
    
    
    
        
            Arena Application
            {% block head}
                Main Page
            {% endblock }

```
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Welcome to arena app </h2>
    {% block  content }

    <p>
        this is base page
    </p>

    {% endblock  }

</body>

</html>
```

**Problem : ** When i visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/register` , this is what i get :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Lod.png

My file Structure :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KvDP.png

And finally my `TEMPLATE_DIRS` var in `settings.py` looks like:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
 )
```

**Django version : 1.7.3**

Comment: You are missing `%` like this  `% }` in all of your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not escaped properly. Should start and end with `{%` and `%}`

Example:

```
{% endblock %}
```

not

```
{% endblock}
```